# Excel file crashing mysteriously with no visible reason

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

**Intro**

A client has a huge Excel file where they create proposal sheets to customers. These "proposal letters" are based on 100 different formulas within around 10 sheets in the Excel file. Every sheet has different macros and formulas. All employees are using *Excel 2010 on Windows 7 machines*.

**The problem** now is when we have further developed this Excel file *(in Excel 2013 on windows 8.1)* added some extra features, updated existing ones,etc. and sent it back to them, it works fine but when a few employees edit the file and send it to other employees it suddenly stops working and the following error comes:

[image]

**Solutions tried.**

**1.** One of these employees that "breaks" the file got his office 2010 reinstalled but that did not fix the problem. Reinstalling Windows **did worked**. But of course they can't reinstall windows to all employees and there are still some that "break" the Excel file when editing it and sending it to others. So it is just a few people which have something different in their computers (not related to the office package I guess since reinstalling office didn't help) that screws up the excel file and then others that don't have any problems with it, get it when they receive the file.

Even funnier - when one of the "bad" employees works with the file and saves it, next time he opens it everything is working just fine. It is only when the file is distributed to others.

**2.** We also removed all the unused references in the VBA code that were not used. That used to be a problem in the past. I also read that it could be some forms (and controls) of Excel that does that but I have removed all unused forms and now it is only one form with a simple textbox and Enter button.

**3.** We set up a virtual machine with office 2010 where we tried to replicate the error but everything works fine there. We asked them to send a broken version of the file but we don't get the error. We have made them install 2-3 hotfixes from Microsoft that relates to this issue but nothing helped (also the update of office in mid December 2014 that broke all Excel controls).

I know this is very broad question but everyone we asked is totally blank.

Comment: Have you tried to make further devolepment with Office2010 and Windows 7?

Comment: Just a guess as it requires more detailed information about the environment every user is working in, but the almost infamous update KB2553154 caused similar issues - If all your users have the update, it may work by getting them to search for the .exd files and deleting them. If they don't, you may need to recreate the workbook avoiding any Active X controls in order for it to work for them. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/3f29c84b-97ad-46f7-9bc0-8648d69336ce/kb2553154-breaks-our-excel-macros?forum=officeitproprevious

Comment: @reporter Yes I tried on 2010 version but on Windows 8.

Comment: @Dave They have all installed the hotfix by Microsoft for this KB (which was actually deleting these .exd files). I don't think any ActiveX controls are used but just the form controls from excel. Will double check though.

Comment: @the guy who just deleted his comment. PLEASE put it back on :) It could have something to do with this problem!

Comment: "I don't think any ActiveX controls are used but just the form controls from excel". The way `TogSep` is referenced suggests it's an ActiveX control.

Comment: @user3964075 you are correct! But the screenshot was from a little older version. We have removed that piece of code. Nicely spotted though :)

Comment: If the code is no longer included, it would be nice to see the part of code and error message where it breaks in the most recent version.

Comment: If you did have ActiveX controls but removed them, the sheet itself may have been corrupted. I have had similar things happen where all references to ActiveX were removed but something was still causing errors in the sheet. The only way I could get around it was to recreate the sheet from scratch with the same code. Do you have any other references to Sheet1 and do they error as well? Or just try ?Sheet1.Name in the Immediate window. This should tell you if the sheet can't be referenced anymore.

Comment: @Dave that could be actually the whole problem then... I am trying to replace all ActiveX controls with normal controls but if you are saying that the sheets might be corrupted then I have to recreate the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried recreating the file? Copying it all into a new workbook. Try saving it as a different excel book? Like .xls rather than .xlsx or a macro enabled book?

Comment: I tried renaming it, closed all office apps. I haven't tried copying it all to a new one because it is close to impossible. There are 20 sheets with all different formulas in them, different macros for each one. I cannot copy it all to a new one... 

I cannot save it as .xls since I will lose all macros.(?) The file cannot work without them.

Comment: The .xls will keep the macros. The newer .xlsx will remove them.

Comment: Hmm I will try in a moment. But again the problem is only in a few of their employees so it is extremely difficult to test and debug that. We don't get that error...

Comment: Only way I can think of testing to see if you can fix it would be to either go down your client and have a PC to play around with and see the problem. Or remote connect to a PC and play around there. One thing to check as well might the if you are using any references to DLL in the macros or ActiveX. Check if the DLL and activeX objects are the same across the board. I had a problem where Excel would not work for certain people. In the end I checked every loaded DLL in the project for their version number and date. Found out the ones that were broken had a bad DLL.

Comment: This is what we are waiting for now. Remote connection to two of their computers - one with working version one with broken. We used to have one strange DLL reference in the code that no one knew what is for (the excel file is from 2006... yeah tell me about it :) but we deleted that.

Comment: That is the only thing I can think of at the moment. Since some work fine and when windows was reinstalled it worked after that. That does suggest that somewhere a DLL or other reference is corrupt. I would check the linked DLLs file version and dates to see if there is any differences. Other than that I am out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: good point there. Thank you for your input. Everything is helpful. We will try to check all that with the customer